# How to lowercase field data in MongoDB find()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my database collection I have two Objects.

```
[
  {"_id" : 1, name: "notLowercased"},
  {"_id" : 2, name: "lowercased"},
]
```

I'm using find and $regex to find name that includes some string.

```
data = await CatalogModel.find({name: {$regex : searcher.toString().toLowerCase()}})
```

For example my input string is "lowercased".

In result I'm getting an array

```
[
  {"_id" : 2, name: "lowercased"},
]
```

But I want to get in result this:

```
[
  {"_id" : 1, name: "notLowercased"},
  {"_id" : 2, name: "lowercased"},
]
```

I'm understand that it's happening becase name "notLowercased" not lowercased.

How to lowercase name fields in this request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `$options` parameter like this: `$options: "i"`.

As explained into [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/):

> `i`: Case insensitivity to match upper and lower cases. For an example, see Perform Case-Insensitive Regular Expression Match.

Even you can avoid `toLowerCase()`

```
data = await CatalogModel.find({name: {$regex : searcher.toString(), "$options": "i" }})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eDcoXZtNOQR) and without `toLowerCase()` [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z_jKAhIADFt)